# Calling custom action without re-rendering page with Rails link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, custom-action, link-to

In _follow.html.slim I am trying to make a link to "Add Friend"  with this:

```
= link_to "Add Friend",  :controller => "relationships", :action => "req"
```

I want it to call the method req in the relationships controller while staying on the same page.  It currently isn't even calling the method and is returning this error: 
No route matches {:controller=>"relationships", :action=>"req", :name=>"Nathan Glass", :age=>"21"}

I'm following this tutorial http://francik.name/rails2010/week10.html and he doesn't define a route for this action.  If this error is correct I guess my confusion is why I need a route for this. Otherwise, what is my problem here?  Thanks!

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
def req
    puts "req called"*10
    # is setting @current_user since the current_user method already returns @current_user?
    @current_user = current_user
    @friend = User.find_by_name(params[:name])
    unless @friend.nil?
        if Relationship.request(@current_user, @friend)
          flash[:notice] = "Friendship with #{@friend.name} requested"
        else
            flash[:error] = "Friendship with #{@friend.name} cannot be requested"
        end
    end
  # render somewhere
end
```

end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you always need to define a route for an action. If you don't, rails doesn't know that your action exists (even if you specify the controller and the action names in your link_to).

For that, you can simply do, in your config/routes.rb file:

```
get 'relationships/req'
```

Now, your req action has a path, relationships_req_path (responding to HTTP GET requests).

Then, if you want to call a controller action while staying on the same page, you can do:

```
link_to "Add as friend", relationships_req_path, remote: true
```

The `remote: true` modifies the link behavior(it will works like an ajax call) and renders the relationships/req.js.erb file by default (which can contain nothing). This file allows use to dynamically add/modify content on the current page.

Comment: Thanks!  So if I were to change the page upon clicking "Add friend" I should make a relationships/req.js.erb file and that is automatically bound to clicking that link?  And otherwise id have to use the js file for the current page and make an event handler for that link? is that right?  thanks for the help Simon.

Comment: When you add a `remote: true`to your link, this call your controller action, execute its code and then render a js file (here, relationships/req.js.erb).

So, for example, you can dynamically add the new friend name to your page by adding this line to the js file:`$('body').append("<%= @friend.name %>")`

Comment: Ok, I have to make the file manually right? And where does this file go?

Comment: Yes. This file is a view. So, it's located in app/views/relationships/req.js.erb

Comment: Sorry for all the questions... I made that folder in that location and tried $(function() {
 alert("hello");
});  and nothing happens when i click that link..

Comment: No problem ;) Did you get an error in your logs? I advise you to make a `tail -f logs/development.log` in your terminal and to click the link in your application page. It should display an error in your logs which can help us.